# What are the new versions of tf.placeholder() and tf.get_variable()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm fairly new to tensorflow, and am wondering why certain important functions are deprecated in the latest version, specifically placeholder and get_variable. For example, I wouldn't be able to do this in TF 2.0:

```
# tf.placeholder()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2,2))
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2,2))
Z = X + Y
x, y = [[1,1], [1,1]], [[2,2], [2,2]]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(Z, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})

# tf.get_variable()
W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [4, 4, 3, 8], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=0))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        # etc ...
```

From what I've learnt so far, these seem like pretty important functions, so I assume their functionality has been replaced with something else in TF 2.0, but I can't seem to figure it out? I know you can use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead, but I am trying to figure out how to do it in TF 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TF 2.0 has changed to an eager execution method, so instead of using sessions and passing data into them, you simply use tf as you would numpy.

```
Z = tf.constant([[1,1], [1,1]]) + tf.constant([[2,2], [2,2]])
```

Tensorflow also has tf.Variable that defines what you might consider a placeholder. Basically a Tensor whose internal is allowed to change. Most keras ops use Variable internal for their computation graphs.